# A way for users to store selections as inputs for later use

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I'm trying to create a way in which a user can store their selections as inputs. Here is an example of what I would like to accomplish:

1) Run the app, it will immediately generate a table with three rows. You name it using `Sample Label` something like "Sample1"

2) Click the `Save Sample` button, which then creates an input as a checkbox within the panel I created, that when clicked, will automatically adjust the filters to how they were when clicking the `Save Sample` button.

3) You then set `disp` to 160 and `hp` to 110, which returns two rows. Repeat the same steps. You name it something like "Sample2" and hit "Save Sample". Now there are two checkboxes: Sample1 and Sample2. You can now toggle them around so the user can pick whatever setting they want. In theory, you can do this as many times as you want.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("disp", "Disp", choices = unique(sort(mtcars$disp)), selected = 275.8),
  selectInput("hp", "hp", choices = unique(sort(mtcars$hp)), selected = 180),
  div(style="display:inline-block", textInput(('sample_name'), label = 'Sample Name',width = 200)),
  div(style="display:inline-block", actionButton(('select_sample'),icon = icon('save'), label = 'Save Sample')),
  panel(h2("User Created Inputs go here")),
  DT::dataTableOutput("cardata")

)

server <- function(input,output,session) {

  compileData <- reactive({

    res <- mtcars %>% filter(hp == input$hp & disp == input$disp)

  })

  output$cardata <- DT::renderDataTable({

    compileData()

  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might be something helpful for you.

You can save the filter settings in a `reactiveValues` dataframe. When filters are created, then a checkbox group will be automatically updated with the new name.

The table data will be filtered based on these selected checkboxes. For this example, if no boxes are selected, then the data shown is based on the two input selections. However, if any checkbox is selected, then the data table will include filtered data based on these choices.

Let me know if this is close to what you had in mind.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("disp", "Disp", choices = unique(sort(mtcars$disp)), selected = 275.8),
  selectInput("hp", "hp", choices = unique(sort(mtcars$hp)), selected = 180),
  div(style="display:inline-block", textInput(('sample_name'), label = 'Sample Name',width = 200)),
  div(style="display:inline-block", actionButton(('select_sample'),icon = icon('save'), label = 'Save Sample')),
  panel(h2("User Created Inputs go here"),
        uiOutput("checkboxes")
        ),
  DT::dataTableOutput("cardata")
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(filters = data.frame(
    id = character(),
    disp = double(),
    hp = double()
  ))

  compileData <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$checkboxes)) {
      mtcars %>% filter(hp == input$hp & disp == input$disp)
    } else {
      merge(mtcars, rv$filters[rv$filters$id %in% input$checkboxes, ], by = c("disp", "hp"))
    }
  })

  output$cardata <- DT::renderDataTable({
    compileData()
  })

  observeEvent(input$select_sample, ignoreInit = FALSE, {
    rv$filters <- rbind(rv$filters, data.frame(
      id = input$sample_name,
      disp = input$disp,
      hp = input$hp
      )
    )
  })

  output$checkboxes <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("checkboxes", "Filters:", choices = rv$filters$id, selected = NULL)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Yes! This looks great! Thanks! One more question: Is there a way they can be saved for future usage?

Comment: Yes, you can. Would take a look at [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html) regarding local vs. remote data storage in a shiny app. Also, if you feel this was helpful, feel free to upvote or accept answer.